# Relationship between Calkin Algebra and Fredholm operators

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, operator-algebras

Given the Calkin Algebra $\pi: B(E) \rightarrow B(E)/K(E)$ we know that $T \in B(E)$ is Fredholm iff $\pi(T)$ is invertible.

I am missing some intuition here. Is there a way to say how such an equivalence class (coset) $\pi(T)$ looks like explicitly (or some example)?

Also we know that $T \in B(E)$ is Fredholm iff there is an operator S such that $ST=I+C_{1}$ and $TS=I+C_2$ with $C_{1},C_2\in K(E)$. My question is - are the compact operator $C_{1}$ and $C_2$ telling us something about in which equivalence class the Fredholm operator lies?

Thanks to everyone that could help me to shed some light on this.

EDIT: Also how does the identity look like in the Calkin Algebra?

Comment: I don't think the compact operators play much of a role while discussing Fredholm operators. $\pi(T)$ is just the collection of operators $T+C$ where $C$ is compact. You can think of them as operators which you get from $T$ by not perturbing it much.

Comment: The Calkin algebra is a wild object. For many purposes it is best understood just as it is defined (i.e., as an algebraic quotient object and not via some representation). For example, although it is an abstract $C^*$ algebra, it does not have a faithful representation as operators on any separable Hilbert space.  See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4056659/is-calkin-algebra-bh-mathcal-kh-isomorphic-to-some-subalgebra-of-bh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no uniqueness in what $C_1$ and $C_2$ are, because there is no uniqueness for $S$. Given $S$ with $ST=I+C_1$ and $TS=I+C_2$, take $K$ any compact operator and form $S'=S+K$. Then
$$
S'T=ST+KT=I+(C_1+K),\qquad\qquad TS'=TS+TK=I+(C_2+K). 
$$
In other words, you are completely free to prescribe at least one of $C_1,C_2$.

I don't think you can expect to get much intuition about what $\pi(T)$ is. After all, the Calkin algebra is what you get when you forget everything finite-dimensional about $B(H)$. What I mean is this. Let $f$ be any linear functional on $B(H)/K(H)$. Then you can define a linear functional $f'$ on $B(H)$ by $f'(T)=f(\pi(T))$. This linear functional $f'$ is zero on every compact operator. In particular it cannot depend in any reasonable way on the entries of $T$ with respect to a basis.